# Getting NameError: uninitialized constant when one class is accessed in another class, both sharing a common module

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, nameerror

**Ruby 2.3.0**

**Rails 4.2.5.1**

**/app/decorators/api/v1/custom_namespace/xyz_decorator.rb**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class CustomNamespace::XyzDecorator < CustomDelegator
    end
  end
end
```

**/app/decorators/api/v1/abc_decorator.rb**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class AbcDecorator < CustomDelegator
      def xyz_decorator
        CustomNamespace::XyzDecorator.new
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When `AbcDecorator` instance tries to access `xyz_decorator` the code breaks with error

```
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant CustomNamespace::XyzDecorator
```

I was expecting `CustomNamespace::XyzDecorator` to get resolved as `Api::V1::CustomNamespace::XyzDecorator` in `Api::V1::AbcDecorator#xyz_decorator` method.

I tried to modify
**/app/decorators/api/v1/custom_namespace/xyz_decorator.rb** the following way but still the same error:

```
module Api
  module V1
    module CustomNamespace
      class XyzDecorator < CustomDelegator
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I use a fully qualified name like shown in following code it works.

**/app/decorators/api/v1/abc_decorator.rb**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class AbcDecorator < CustomDelegator
      def xyz_decorator
        Api::V1::CustomNamespace::XyzDecorator.new
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Can anybody please make me understand what is going on and why my first version of code don't work?

P.S: There are no such files defined which explicitly defines just the modules:

**/app/decorators/api.rb**

```
module Api
end
```

**/app/decorators/api/v1.rb**

```
module Api
 module V1
 end
end
```

**/app/decorators/api/v1/custom_namespace.rb**

```
module Api
 module V1
   module CustomNamespace
   end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar problem.  You could try making your namespaces as follows:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class AbcDecorator < CustomDelegator
      def xyz_decorator
        CustomNamespace::XyzDecorator.new
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And

```
module Api
  module V1
    class CustomNamespace::XyzDecorator < CustomDelegator
    end
  end
end
```

I am not 100% sure, but I think that it only adds the namespace automatically if the model name that you are trying to call is defined exactly as it is called - i.e. if you call `A::B.new` under more namespaces then you have to define it `class A::B`. Also, by declaring classes with the short (`A::B`) version it does not automatically namespace other models called within the class.

Comment: Thanks. What you have suggested is already mentioned in my post.

Comment: @JiggneshhGohel sorry, did not notice that :/